# Counting duplicates in datagridview and displaying number of duplicates

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, duplicates

Hi I am trying to count the number of duplicates in my unbound datagrid.

My problem is that when I clear my string it then starts the count a fresh count and dismisses the previous duplicate entries but if I do not clear the string I get the number of duplicates as the 2nd digit in my string this is fine but I need it do search for duplicates and display the number or duplicates of that sort in the column

I press the button.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        DataGridView2.ColumnCount = 7

        DataGridView2.Columns(0).Name = ""
        DataGridView2.Columns(1).Name = ""
        DataGridView2.Columns(2).Name = ""
        DataGridView2.Columns(3).Name = ""
        DataGridView2.Columns(4).Name = ""
        DataGridView2.Columns(5).Name = ""
        DataGridView2.Columns(6).Name = "UID"

        Dim row As String() = New String() {"", "", "", "", "", "", "" & Label1.Text & "" & Label4.Text & " " & Label3.Text & " " & Label5.Text & " " & Label6.Text & ""}
        DataGridView2.Rows.Add(row)

Timer7.Start()

End Sub
```

Then This

```
Private Sub Timer7_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer7.Tick
  Dim date1 As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy")
    Form3.DataGridView1.ColumnCount = 7
    Form3.DataGridView1.Columns(0).Name = "SERIAL"
    Form3.DataGridView1.Columns(1).Name = "PORT"
    Form3.DataGridView1.Columns(2).Name = "Attempt"
    Form3.DataGridView1.Columns(3).Name = "PEAK IM3"
    Form3.DataGridView1.Columns(4).Name = "Date of Data"
    Form3.DataGridView1.Columns(5).Name = "Time of Data"
    Form3.DataGridView1.Columns(6).Name = "UID"
    Dim row As String() = New String() {"" & Label1.Text & "", "" & Label4.Text & " " & Label3.Text & " " & Label5.Text & " " & Label6.Text & "", "" & Label15.Text & "", "", date1, CStr(TimeOfDay), "" & Label1.Text & "" & Label4.Text & " " & Label3.Text & " " & Label5.Text & " " & Label6.Text & ""}
    Form3.DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)

    Dim dc As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)()
    Dim clV As String

    For i As Integer = 0 To Form3.DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1

        If Not Form3.DataGridView1.Rows(i).IsNewRow Then

            clV = Me.DataGridView2(6, i).Value.ToString()

            If Not dc.ContainsKey(clV) Then
                dc.Add(clV, +1)
            Else
                dc(clV) += 1
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()

    For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer) In dc
        sb.AppendLine(String.Format("{0} ", kvp.Value))
    Next

    Label15.Text = sb.ToString()

    Timer7.Stop()
End Sub
```

I have spent 2 days trying to figure this out and need some advice on what to do.

Comment: what do you mean by `clear my string`? **If** you want the dupe count to last beyond that code block, you need to declare dc outside that event or Sub (we dont have any context).  Otherwise when that SUB ends, dc is disposed of.

Comment: My string that Stringbuilder creates it adds the counted amount to the end and if I go back to search for a previous value it changes the first number in the string this is good but I just need current value not all the values of all the searches. if it is say 2 for a serch of the word "cat" I get 2 but then if I search for "dog" i get 24 if dog exists 4 times  then if I search cat and it has bee added again I get 34

Comment: I dont quite follow, but the sb you build seems to be designed that way.  try this to see it clarifies things: `sb.AppendLine(String.Format("{0} - {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value + 1))`  you seem to be glueing the results of all dupes in dc together: "2" & "4" = "24".  Adding cat again should be "242", so there might be another problem. (also seems the CRLF is missing, make sure the textbox is Multiline, I dunno)

Comment: This will give me the same result but with the search word in each entry. cat2dog4

Comment: search word??  This isnt scanning the DGV for a search term, it is counting how many dupes of Col(6) are in the grid (are you **trying** to count rows with matching text in Col(6)??) . but it should have shown  "cat - 2" "dog - 4", not "dog - 24".  Edit your post to show the whole SUB for this please.  also `kvp.Value + 1` is wrong - leave off the `+1`, you already increment the count when you find a match

Comment: `...search word in each entry. cat2dog4` - yes, that is what your code is written to do more or less.  without the key name, it would be "24".  One problem is that AppendLine seems not to add a CRLF.  Do you actually want it to search for a specific UID and count the dupes of that?  The code is not comparing the DGV columnn to some text value it is counting  dupes of everything.  Also, the timer seems unneeded - why not just a button click?

Comment: The reason for the timer is the program is to be used to save data form a PIM test in work that saves its own .CSV file this allows the other program to do its work. I want to keep a record of the amount of times I test the same port on each antenna if it is a duplicate I want to store this information.

Comment: I had it in my head it was counting by searching this has me confused

Comment: if you want to count the dupes of "cat" then you need a textbox for the user to type the search value or something similar - like maybe count the number of dupes of the row clicked.  there isnt any external variable in that sub like what to search and count

Comment: Ok I Will try this thank you for your advice and help. When I solve this I will post the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

Had to bind my data to database datatable.

Then I used this to make a filter button in the toolstrip.

Filter column_heading LIKE ? + '%'

Then using the code above it gave the correct count.

Steps were as follows

1. Add data to DGV
2. Save to DGV to Database
3. Filter
4. Count results
5. Refresh DGV